# list not working in a query

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

Can anyone tell me why this query will only process if I hard code `phone_type`

```
#model.py

class ClientPhone(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, editable=False)
    ...
    phone_type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=PHONE_CHOICES)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=24)

# models.py

PHONE_CHOICES = (
    ('home', 'Home'),
    ('home2', 'Home 2'),
    ('mobi', 'Mobile'),
    ('mobi2', 'Mobile 2'),
    ('work', 'Work'),
    ('work2', 'Work 2'),
)

# views.py

    phones = [ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=i_clientKEY).filter(phone_type=k).latest('created') for k, v in PHONE_CHOICES]

# shell

>>> from client.models import ClientPhone
>>> phones = [ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=1).filter(phone_type=k).latest('created') for k, v in PHONE_CHOICES]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 395, in latest
    return obj.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 341, in get
        % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: ClientPhone matching query does not exist.
>>> phones = [ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=1).filter(phone_type='home').latest('created') for k, v in PHONE_CHOICES]
>>> phones
[<ClientPhone: ClientPhone object>, <ClientPhone: ClientPhone object>, <ClientPhone: ClientPhone object>, <ClientPhone: ClientPhone object>, <ClientPhone: ClientPhone object>, <ClientPhone: ClientPhone object>]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`latest()` raises an exception if no matches are found, so unless each client has every single `phone_type`, you will get an exception when a client doesn't have one of the `home`, `home2`, `mobi`, etc choices.

In the second example, you are only ever looking for `home`, which apparently has a valid result for `latest()`.

One method:

```
latest_phones = []
for k, v in PHONE_CHOICES:
    try:
        latest_phones.append(ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=i_clientKEY, phone_type=k).latest('id'))
    except ClientPhone.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Another more efficient method if you're interested in only some specific values from the model:

```
client_phone_numbers = ClientPhone.objects.filter(client=i_clientKEY)\
     .order_by('-created').values_list('phone_type', 'phone_number').distinct()

# returns list of all `phone_type` and its latest `phone_number` for this client
# if you don't need all phone types, specifically filter them in the first filter
# eg: filter(phone_type__in=['home','mobi'])
```

Comment: should I just pass the query through a `try` then?

Comment: that would fail the lookup on your first exception! I'd just iterate through `PHONE_CHOICES` and wrap each get attempt. Posting an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_or_create()` method instead of `latest()` to ensure that all phone types are in the database.

Comment: Don't really need to create it if it doesn't exist. Sorry :(